# Creating a new variable that counts the # of duplicate values from another variable in R

Tags: r, count, dataframe, unique

I am trying to a create a new variable in R that gives a unique (ordered) numeric value to each observation based on the duplicate values in another variable. I have put below what the data looks like and what I would like it too look like. Can anyone help?

```
name <- c("Alex", "Alex", "Alex", "Bill", "Bill", "Cathy")
purchase <- c("hat", "bag", "book", "bag", "book", "book")
individual_purchase_No <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1)
```

## What the data looks like:

```
purchase.data <- data.frame(name, purchase)
```

## What I want the data to look like:

```
purchase_order.data <- data.frame(name, purchase, individual_purchase_No)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
purchase.data %>% group_by(name) %>%
                  mutate(individual_purchase_No = 1:n())
## Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
## Groups: name [3]
## 
##     name purchase individual_purchase_No
##   (fctr)   (fctr)                  (int)
## 1   Alex      hat                      1
## 2   Alex      bag                      2
## 3   Alex     book                      3
## 4   Bill      bag                      1
## 5   Bill     book                      2
## 6  Cathy     book                      1
```

A base R solution is for instance:

```
purchase.data$individual_purchase_No <- sequence(table(purchase.data$name))
```

Table counts the number of appearances of each name, and sequence then creates for each number `n` the sequence `1:n`.